# Dynamic Page Render On Demand Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

So, I am working on a simple Next.Js app. It's just a Lyrical Page but I'm running onto some issues. I'm new to Next.Js and this is my first project. So, here is my problem:

I have a **dynamic** set of pages/folders which looks like this:

- songs (empty folder)
- [singer] (child of songs containng just an index.jsx)
- [title] (child of [singer] containing another index.jsx)

Now in my [title] - index.jsx im rendering a simple page providing lyrics for a specific song.
My problem is that I want to count views (every time someone opens this page) for each song sepertly. I have the following code:

```
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
const res = await fetch(`${process.env.PROXY}api/lyrics/post/${encodeURIComponent(context.params.title)}`);

const data = await res.json();

const send = await fetch(`${process.env.PROXY}api/lyrics/views/${data.post._id}`);

return {
  props: {
    data: data.post,
    message: 200
  }
}
```

}

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.PROXY}api/lyrics/getAll`);

  const data = await res.json();

  const paths = data.all.map((name) => ({ params: { singer: name.singer.toString(), title: name.title.toString() } }));

  return {
      paths: paths,
      fallback: 'blocking'
  }
```

}

The problem is I know getStaticProps renders **only** on build time, however, I want to render every time so that I can count the views with my `send` variable.

Can someone please help me figure this out? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You would have to fetch your page views in React instead of NextJS. For this you could use a `useEffect`

Comment: Alternatively you could use NextJs' `GetServerSideProps` which fetches the data on every request before the page renders. This is a good for SEO but a bit slow. So considering your use case I would go for the useEffect.